# Traffic counter on openwrt?

Tags: openwrt

Are there any (not a resource hog) solutions to have statistics about the traffic on an OpenWrt router? :O e.g.: traffic per IP address, monthly statistics, etc. :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To monitor traffic and other information about my OpenWrt router I use munin.  I detail my experience in my posting on [Monitoring with Munin](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/monitoring-with-munin/).  It doesn't specifically address traffic by IP address, which a tool like `ntop` might be better suited for.

The firewall can be configured to gather such accounting data, but you would need to extract and summarize it.  I use shorewall-lite to build my firewall rules.  I haven't posted on my experiences yet.

Answer (score 3):

Traffic reporting on OpenWRT is not much different than on other Linux platforms. You can use a shell to look at the interface statistics or use one of the several reporting / monitoring packages.

Personally I use collected to gather some data from my OpenWRT routers and build graphs on another machine along with some other relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying collectd

I'm following this [neat article](https://advanxer.com/blog/2013/02/openwrt-monitoring-using-collectd/?ak_action=reject_mobile), and it is great